# How to use python to invoke events on a desktop?

Tags: python

how to use python to invoke events , like a torrent application and also feeding it with a torrent file in linux ?

Comment: Invoke events on a desktop? What does that even mean?

Comment: Maybe he means starting applications?

Answer (score 1):

Most bittorrent apps on Linux will accept a `.torrent` file as a command line parameter. With some (notable Azureus//Vuze) you may need to use a fully qualified pathname, which you can get with `os.path.abspath`. Then just use your favorite method of running programs from Python like the `subprocess` module or even `os.system`.

If you need to do anything more sophisticated than that you can try looking for a client that supports [dbus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a program from python you can do it like this:

```
import os
cmd = '/path/to/program'
os.system(cmd)
```

I cannot say anything about running your bittorrent program, since you haven't said anything about which program you are using, but calling it with an url is probably straight forward (just find the right switch and add the switch and url to the `cmd` variable above).